# disable "pull to ..." on lightning component in sf1

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components

Built a lightning component; put it as a component tab in sf1.

Is there a way to disable the "pull to refresh" and "pull to Show More" at the top/bottom of the page if that makes no sense for this tab?

Can a component request that the page be non-pullable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that I found a better solution:

In your .cmp file, add an aura:id to the top-level , e.g.

Then define the following renderer:

```
({
    afterRender : function(component, helper) {
       this.superAfterRender(); 
       var targetEl = component.find("mainapp").getElement();
       targetEl.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }, false); 
    }
})
```

Comment: I think you are missing the aura:id example you're referring to, but otherwise this looks great.

Comment: Hi Steve or Christian.. Where do you add the aura:id in the component file?  if I try to do <aura:component aura:id="MyApp"  I get an error upon save.  This appears to be correct solution as I can see event firing upon refresh but cannot target the correct component.  THANK YOU!!

Comment: guys, were you able to get it working? I'm also receiving Error on Save if we pass aura:id into aura:component ...

Comment: If you have only one top-level element in your component, `component.getElement()` is sufficient to grab that component's root node—no `aura:id` is necessary.

Comment: i have tried this but seems not working for me. but for me required this feature to implement in one functionality. please help if you find any work around

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, because I can't get the Id component.
Somone Can help me? tks,

Comment: I love "features" that are forced on us :)

Comment: I added it to my component and it doesn't seem to work. It disables scrolling at all, but pull to refresh is still enabled...

Answer (score 3):

Workaround: add the component to lightning app builder (it can be the only thing on the page).

It'll have a header (name of the app) but no pull to refresh/see more.

Comment: That technique doesn't seem to work in Winter '16. Have you figured out any other workarounds?

Comment: I think you're right.  I put your answer on top now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Steve works great! You don't even need to mess around with a renderer if you add a container that takes up the full height of the screen

```
<div ontouchmove="{!c.handleTouchMove}"></div>
```

Then in your controller write the handler

```
handleTouchMove: function(component, event, helper) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

This has the added benefit of being able to isolate the non pull behavior to only a section of the screen.

Comment: I used in on my leaflet map component, but it blocked also the ability to touch/move/zoom the map.

Comment: Thanks Scott! This was a huge help for me getting a form on a lightning component to scroll properly. I needed to make my component work for an iPad and this made the difference!

Comment: I added it to my component and it doesn't seem to work. It disables scrolling at all, but pull to refresh is still enabled...