# Disable "Pull to refresh" in Salesforce Mobile Lightning component without breaking scroll

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I've tried to do couple of fixes that were outlined here:
[disable "pull to ..." on lightning component in sf1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83034/disable-pull-to-on-lightning-component-in-sf1)

However, both of them break scroll:

1. Scott's suggestion breaks scrolling all-together - can't scroll down.
2. Steve's solution does scroll, but only the viewport itself...

There's also this [Salesforce1 - Disable pull to refresh](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155190/salesforce1-disable-pull-to-refresh), which seems to be on a right path, but with quick cleanup ([here](https://gist.github.com/sjurgis/7a648811af2a99f4657b3158e43667a7)) doesn't seem to work.

Was also thinking perhaps there's an internal platform event handler that I can override - perhaps platform emits an event once it detects pull to refresh? Seems unlikely tho.

Note - I am trying to implement this in an abstract component.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Don't think so. I was told "Big things coming to Salesforce Mobile" but haven't heart since...

Comment: I thought so... Scrolling issues in sf mobile app are such a pain. :(